# ColdFusion 9 Custom Tag adds whitespace to strings

Tags: string, coldfusion, custom-tags

Despite suppressing whitespace and trimming the variable, ColdFusion 9 always adds whitespaces on both sides of variable outputs. Here is an example of my code and output that drives me crazy;

This is the custom tag part:

```
    <cfprocessingdirective suppresswhitespace="Yes">
        <cfquery name="get_something" datasource="some_dsn">
        SELECT SOMETHING FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE SOME_VALUES = PARAMETERS
        </cfquery>
        <cfoutput>#Trim(get_something.something)#</cfoutput>
    </cfprocessingdirective>
```

after dumping this value by using,

```
<cfdump var="#get_something.something#">
```

I get the exact string that in db. There is no spaces on both sides of the sting here. But when i use this tag on other pages as shown below;

```
<cf_my_tag param=someparam param2=someotherparam>
```

I get the string with whitespaces on both sides.

This is what happens after i use:

```
(<cf_my_tag params>) = ( some string from db )
```

...and this is what I want:

```
(some string from db)
```

Since i can't manipulate custom tags at where i use them (like trimmig or string processes etc), I think I need something is custom tag part.

What could be the reason or what am I supposed to do to get rid of these whitespaces? Could it be some configuration problems in ColdFusion Server?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 4):

Your heading is misleading, as it's nothing to do with `trim()`, which works fine. You are suggesting this code is the culprit:

```
<cfoutput>#Trim(get_something.something)#</cfoutput>
```

However I think if you modify it to be this:

```
<cfoutput>[#Trim(get_something.something)#]</cfoutput>
```

You will see no unexpected whitespace between the square brackets.

What you then go on to say in the rest of your question is that it's *this* that emits the extraneous whitespace:

```
<cf_my_tag param=someparam param2=someotherparam>
```

So the question is really one asking about custom tags emitting unexpected whitespace, which is - I'm afraid - something custom tags are noted for.

You can mitigate this in part by putting all your code within the tag's file in `<cfsilent>` tags.

Comment: You are right, I'm going to edit heading. Then I ll try something more in my tag file.

Comment: So, regarding your suggestion helped me to solve the issue. Still I don't know why this happening but after i changed my code to a simple way and separated irrelevant parts from the tag file, it surprisingly got solved. I think problem is coming out from text editor on the server cos it still happens within no valid reason in some files written on servers text editor. Maybe it adds a single whitespace on physical file, i couldn't get. Well, thank you.